# Swift chaining optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm running Yosemite public beta & Xcode6 Beta 4

Based on the OSX SceneKit template, I'm trying to determine what node was clicked on.  Here is the mouseDown function, mostly from the template code.

The comment labeled #1 works, which if great, but I'm trying to understand why the code comments #2, #3, and #4 don't compile, or what the errors are really telling me.

Searching the errors I'm not finding results that appear to apply to my case.

the error for #2 seems to usually apply to type casting, and I wouldn't think there is any type casting going on here.

the error for #3 has me totally lost.

and the error for #4 seems like SCNNode doesn't have a name property, but it certainly does.

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    /* Called when a mouse click occurs */

    // check what nodes are clicked
    let p = gameView.convertPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow, fromView: nil)
    let hitResults = gameView.hitTest(p, options: nil)

    // check that we clicked on at least one object
    if (hitResults.count > 0){

        // retrieved the first clicked object
        let result: AnyObject = hitResults[0]

// #1 This works
        if let myNode: SCNNode = result.node? {
            if myNode.name? == "Die" {
                println("Node is named Die")
            }
        }

// #2 This does not work
        // error: Could not find an overload for the 'node' that accepts the supplied arguments
        if let myNode = result.node? {
            if myNode.name? == "Die" {
                println("Node is named Die")
            }
        }

// #3 This does not work either
        // error: Type 'String?' does not confrom to protocol '_RawOptionSet'
        if result.node?.name? == "Die" {
            println("Node is named Die")
        }

// #4 This does not work either
        // error: 'SCNNode!' does not have a member named 'name'
        if let myName = result.node?.name? {
            if myName == "Die" {
                println("Node is named Die")
            }
        }

        // get its material
        let material = result.node!.geometry.firstMaterial;

        // highlight it
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

        // on completion - unhighlight
        SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock() {
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

            material.emission.contents = NSColor.blackColor()

            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }

        material.emission.contents = NSColor.redColor()

        SCNTransaction.commit()

    }

    super.mouseDown(theEvent)
}
```

Comment: What's with the question marks you're putting on the end of all those, e.g. in `if let myNode: SCNNode = result.node?`, what's the question mark for? I can't see that anywhere in the Swift language documentation. It looks a bit like optional chaining, but you're not chaining anything onto it?

Comment: Page 489-508 in the swift book.

Comment: I can't see anything there in the book that covers that. Am I going blind (I have the latest edition)? To put it another way, what's the difference between `if let myNode: SCNNode = result.node` — which is what I would use — and `if let myNode: SCNNode = result.node?`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failures of #2, #3, and #4 are all because of the lack of type.  You say:

> the error for #2 seems to usually apply to type casting, and I wouldn't think there is any type casting going on here.

However, you declared `result` to be `AnyObject` while you're attempting to access it as an `SCNNode`, so there's certainly some type cast that needs to happen.

I've seen this before as well working with dictionaries.  Not only did I get explicit about the type, I also tested the type beforehand:

```
var item: AnyObject? = nil
item = map["SWLFlexFormat"]
if let value: AnyObject = item {
    configuration.formatter = getConfiguredFlexFormatter(configuration, item: value);
}

func getConfiguredFlexFormatter(configuration: LoggerConfiguration, item: AnyObject) -> LogFormatter? {
    if let formatString: String = item as? String {
        var formatter = FlexFormatter.logFormatterForString(formatString);
        return formatter
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I guess what is confusing about that, is because #4 was the first thing I tried.  So result is AnyObject then why does the error know its a SCNNode and then complain that SCNNode doesn't have a member name.
Changing the line where I declare result to
    if let result = hitResults[0] as? SCNHitTestResult {